# Both mysql statements must be true

Tags: php, sql

Both feedid and merchant must be true. Now it also does not show result where merchant is true.

I tried already for hours whit 2 statements at once but always get wrong results. i want results that are not already in map feedid is not unique but feedid whit merch is.

```
$sql = "SELECT products.name, products.sku, products.feedid, products.brand,
    products.merchant, map.merch, map.productid 
  from products, map 
  where (products.feedid != map.productid && products.merchant != map.merch) 
    and products.name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'  
     or products.sku LIKE '%" . $search . "%' ";
```

What I try to do here is that products.feedid and products.merchant must both not match.

Example:

products.feedid has the folowing result (101)(102)(101)(105)

products.merchant has the folowing result (shop)(shop)(othershop)(othershop)

In map table there is the result map.productid (101) whit merch(shop)

I want my sql query to show (102)(shop)  (101)(othershop) and (105)(othershop)

And not (101)(shop)

Now it only shows (105)(othershop)

Comment: I added newlines to the SQL so we could read it without horizontal scrolling.

Comment: you can add new line without introducing errors.

Comment: @Dave . . . Can you provide sample input and expected results?  You query and explanation don't make clear exactly what you want.

Comment: example will be products.feedid(2) products.merchant(shop) and map.feedid(1) map.merch(shop) This wil now not show up because shop is there.

Comment: Please edit your question to include **clear** sample input and expected results, as @GordonLinoff asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need another set of parentheses

```
$sql ="SELECT products.name, products.sku, products.feedid, products.brand, products.merchant, map.merch, map.productid 
from products, map 
where (products.feedid != map.productid && products.merchant != map.merch) and (products.name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'  or products.sku LIKE '%" . $search . "%' )";
```

Comment: I still lose all the results from a merchant when i do that

Comment: For this case, both conditions have to be true in order to get results, isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes per result so for instance if a row in map = 1 and test and a other row is 2 and test. And the products have 1 and test then only the first must be not displayed. Now it seems that both are not displayed because they have both test.